# Targeting multiple Windows versions

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm developing my application under Windows 8.1 but I want to also target Windows 7 and 8. Can I compile executables for different platforms other than the one I'm developing in, and if so how can I accomplish this?

PS. I'm currently using visual studio 2012 professional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special. The operating system on which you run your build system is largely irrelevant. Simply don't use any newer features that are not available with Windows 7, and your executable will run. The mechanism described in ["Using the Windows Headers"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745.aspx) would help you avoid using such a feature accidentally.

Comment: Except for the Internet Explorer version problem, because MSDN recently became useless: they removed the version infos from the COM interfaces definitions.

Comment: what about if I don't know exactly which features are supported or not? I was looking for a way for the compiler to let me know a specific feature isn't supported for the target platform.

Comment: Use the link provided by Igor and set your target to Windows 7. If you use a "8 only" feature, compiler will tell you.